# Are nested double quotes incorrect in XML?

Tags: xml

I use Python to parse a XML file but it fails because the XML file has nested double quotes, for example,

```
<number="4" word="start" sentence="I said, "start!"" />
```

If I change it to be

```
<number="4" word="start" sentence="I said, 'start!'" />
```

then the Python XML parse can work with it.

I wonder if XML doesn't allow nested double quotes, or is it just Python? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's XML that prevents doing what you are trying to do. You can use single quotes for your attribute value:

```
<number="4" word="start" sentence='I said, "start!"' />
```

The part of the standard that states that both single quotes and double quotes can be used to delimit attributes is [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#NT-AttValue).

You can use `&quot;` to represent double quotes:

```
 <number="4" word="start" sentence="I said, &quot;start!&quot;" />
```

`&quot;` looks funky but it is definitely correct. As the [standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#syntax) states:

> To allow attribute values to contain both single and double quotes, the apostrophe or single-quote character (') may be represented as "`&apos;`", and the double-quote character (") as "`&quot;`".

Comment: Thanks! WIll it be fine if I replace the inner double quotes to be single quotes, like the example in my post?

Comment: Sure! I did not suggest that because typically people are very attached to the specific information they want to put in their attributes. :)

Comment: If my text has too many such nested double quotes for manually changing them, how would you recommend to change them?

Comment: If this is XML you are generating from some other source, the easiest way is when you generate an attribute to just replace all double quotes in the value with `&quot;`. But it sounds like what you are talking about is a file that someone already created and you have to clean it for parsing. I'm not seeing an easy way out of this. I'd probably use Emacs with some custom macros and regular expressions. There's no simple rule to apply. (If there were, then we would not have to deal with `&quot;`.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes that's incorrectly formatted XML. It's almost like saying this:
`<number="4" word="start" sentence="I said, " start!"" />`

Where `start!` seems like an attribute but again, incorrectly formatted. Double quotes need to be escaped, like this:

`<number="4" word="start" sentence="I said, &quot;start!&quot;" />`

Answer (score 1):

Flip your quote ordering:

```
<number="4" word="start" sentence='I said, "start!"' />
```

Answer (score -3):

Yes because for the first double quotes closes your statement
"I said, " then your program read START as tag. if you want to use double quotes you can use this.

```
sentence = "I said, \"start!\" "
```

Comment: No, XML does not use backslash as an escape.